# Email encryption

Tags: windows, email, encryption

Looking for a program that is able to send encrypted emails. The trick being, I want to ensure the private keys are transferable by physical means (USB etc.)

- Must support private and public keys;
- Must allow keys to be imported, exported and transported;
- Must operate on Windows.

If possible, I would accept an add-on feature to Outlook which supports this process.

Comment: This question is not asking for a specific tool as such, more asking if a program you've already used does XYZ function. I'll go ahead and edit your question to make it more related to your question.

Comment: Joshua, Try https://www.symantec.com/products/information-protection/encryption/desktop-email-encryption as an option. Allows integration with Outlook, the program is externally used. Although, this is a rather expensive solution.

Comment: Also worth noting, I **believe** it possible with PGP Keys in Thunderbird - http://mzl.la/1BsOGiZ